# awesome-wm opens webstorm menus in seperate dialog in the top left

Tags: awesome-wm

Somehow, when I run webstorm in Awesome-wm, the file menus open in seperate dialogs with the title "win32", but the submenus are unreachable, because they open in the top left, rather than where the cursor is at that moment.

Is anyone familiar with this behaviour or knows some sort of fix to it? Would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This most likely is related to the JavaRuntime. There is a bug report @Jetbrains about this behaviour:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-709

Switching the boot jdk from the built-in Jetbrains JDK to OpenJDK should help. If not already done, install OpenJDK. In the IDE press ctrl-shift-A and enter "Switch Boot JDK". In the dialog, select openjdk, then restart the IDE. After installing openjdk you might have to reboot first to have openjdk available in the dialog.
More about it here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html

Comment: The issue resolved itself gladly. Buy thanks for the answer, it is really good. I can not verify it but i will accept anyway